# How can I create a loop for string symbols?

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

I have a variable with string `let x = '12345';`. I need to find the sum of the digits of this number,
so I used `Number()` function to change the type.

Now I have this peace of code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  let o = Number(x[i]) + Number(x[x+1]);
  console.log(o);
}
```

I know that it's wrong code, so I need help.

I want to solve this question with for-loop and I don't know how to sum the symbols of the `x` variable.

Comment: define a variable outside of for loop, and keep adding value at each index to that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop should look at 1 character at-a-time and add it to an accumulating value declared outside the loop. Log the result after the loop completes.

Example with for-loop:

```
let x = "12345";

let total = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  total += Number(x[i]);
};
console.log(total);
```

Various looping examples:

```js
let x = "12345";

let forLoopTotal = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  forLoopTotal += Number(x[i]);
}
console.log({ forLoopTotal });

let forOfTotal = 0;
for (let c of x) {
  forOfTotal += Number(c);
}
console.log({ forOfTotal });

let reduceTotal = Array.from(x).reduce((total, c) => total + Number(c), 0);
console.log({ reduceTotal });
```

Answer (score 1):

At the first you can change string to an array after that you can use from reduce() method.

```
let x = '12345';
let arr = x.split('');

  const total = arr.reduce(function (acc, value, i, arr) {
      return acc + Number(value);
}, 0);

console.log(total);
```

I hope it helps you!